# Xaml Bindings - updating my backer variable based on the TargetNullValue

Tags: xaml, binding, targetnullvalue

When Binding, I know it is possible to create a [fallback value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx); If your xaml can't find the property you are binding to, it will 'fall back' to whatever you put here. You can also create a [targetNullValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), just in case your binding returns null.

Many people seem to struggle with how you to go about setting up a fallback value - (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217254/display-a-default-datatemplate-in-a-contentcontrol-when-its-content-is-null-or-e) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632597/targetnullvalue-for-visibility-thats-bound-to-a-boolean)), but these don't quite answer my question, which is:

**If my binding evaluates to Null, is there a way to update it to the targetNullValue**? - I don't just want it to display on the UI, I want it to change my backing variable itself from Null to the fallback value.

Once IntitializeComponent(); is called, I want *myBackerString* to `return "overrideNull";`

```
<ContentControl 
    Content="{Binding myBackerString, 
              TargetNullValue='overrideNull', 
              Mode=TwoWay}"
/>

public String myBackerString
{
    {    get { return (String)GetValue(testBackerProperty); }
    {    set { SetValue(testBackerProperty); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty testBackerProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("testBacker", typeof(String), typeof(myClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```